# How to generate unique title within <title></title> tag based on clicked link - using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to generate a unique title when a user clicks on a link in this page:

[image: webpage]

When a user clicks on one of those links, the tab title should correspond to the csv.

Here is a little of my HTML for each page style (where the title tags are):

```
    <title>Sortable & Responsive Table</title> //this is the current title that shows up on the tabs, but these must be unique, like Arc CSV or Coral CSV

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <style>
     {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
 }
 body {
       font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;
 }
#page-wrap {
      margin: 50px;
}
p {
     margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I have a single JavaScript file that parses for the csv that was clicked and loads that corresponding table within the link -- so I figure that generating a unique title would be just as simple (if not simpler):

Window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function ()

```
     {

         var query = location.search;

         query = query.slice(1);

         var queryArray = query.split("&");

         var file;
         for (var i=0; i<queryArray.length; i++)
         {

             if (queryArray[i].slice(0, 4) === "csv=")
             {

                 file = queryArray[i].slice(4);
             }
         }

         var path = "../reservations/"+file+".csv";

         d3.csv("../reservations/"+file+".csv", function(error, data) {
               //generates unique table here
                                });
```

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript/HTML, but I'm always learning.  Please let me know. Sorry if I missed anything, let me know if I should supply additional code/information. I appreciate it!

Comment: `window.document.title = file;`

Answer (score 0):

To change the title of a page is simple like that:

```
// this changes the title
document.title = "New Title"

// create a higher order function
function setTitle(title) {
  document.title = title
}

// and use it like this..    
setTitle("New Title")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<li><a onclick="change(theFile)"></a></li>

<script>
var theFile = "What you want";

function change(csv){
document.title = csv;
};
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript function, change these lines:

```
var path = "../reservations/"+file+".csv";
d3.csv("../reservations/"+file+".csv", function(error, data) {
               //generates unique table here
                                });
```

to

```
var path = "../reservations/"+file+".csv";
    d3.csv("../reservations/"+file+".csv", function(error, data) {
    window.document.title=path;  //// or whatever title you want to set
                   //generates unique table here
                                    });
```